# Plotting the summation over different values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, math, plot, sympy

I have the following summation function:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import var, Sum, pi, factorial, limit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 
import scipy.misc


def b_func(x, k):
    n = np.arange(k)
    X, N = np.meshgrid(x, n)
    val =((X**(2*N)) / factorial(2*N)
    return np.sum(val)

x0 = np.pi/2
x1= 2 * np.pi

x = np.linspace(x0, x1, 100)
  
for k in [0]:
    plt.plot(x, b_func(x, k))

plt.show()
```

and I would like to plot it for the following values: `[0]`
but unfortunately I get this error message:
[image]

and this:

[image]

any ideas on the this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using sympy's `factorial` on numerical data types: if possible, avoind mixing symbolic functions with numerical data.

Replace sympy's `factorial` with the one from scipy:

```
from scipy.special import factorial
```

After that you are going to get the plot:

[image]